# Adding Helper Methods to Mongo Shell

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell

Is there any way of adding "helper" methods to the `mongo` shell that loads each time you use it?

Basically whenever you want to query by `_id`, you have to do something like this.

```
db.collectionName.findOne({_id: ObjectId('THIS-IS-AN-OBJECTID')})
```

Whenever I'm going to be doing a lot of command line commands, I alias the `ObjectId` function to make it easier to type.

```
var ob = ObjectId;
db.collectionName.findOne({_id: ob('AN-OBJECTID')})
db.collectionName.findOne({_id: ob('ANOTHER-ONE')})
db.collectionName.findOne({_id: ob('ANOTHER')})
```

It would be pretty chill if there was a way of either running a specified piece of JS / add a chunk of code that runs each time `mongo` is pulled up from the shell.  I checked out MongoDB's CLI documentation, but didn't see anything like that available, so I figured I would ask here.

I know there is a possibility of using this nefariously, so this might be a situation where it might be unsupported by the `mongo` shell by default.  This might be a situation where we can create a helper bash script of some sort to launch the shell, then inject keyboard input to create the helper `ob` function?  Not sure how this could be tackled personally, but would love some insight on how to do something like this, either natively or through a helper script of some sort.

Comment: It's in the documentation. [`.mongorc.js`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/#mongorc-js-file)

Comment: @BlakesSeven Haha thanks!  I swear I looked in the docs and didn't find anything.  I can't believe I didn't see this too, I'm pretty sure I went over that page.  If you want to throw this in as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: More Interesting that this does not seem to get a mention here already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want code to execute every time you launch the shell, then whatever you place in [`.mongorc.js`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/#mongorc-js-file) will be run on launch:

> ***.mongorc.js File***
>
> *When starting, mongo checks the user’s HOME directory for a JavaScript file named .mongorc.js. If found, mongo interprets the content of .mongorc.js before displaying the prompt for the first time. If you use the shell to evaluate a JavaScript file or expression, either by using the --eval option on the command line or by specifying a .js file to mongo, mongo will read the .mongorc.js file after the JavaScript has finished processing. You can prevent .mongorc.js from being loaded by using the --norc option.*

So simply define your variable association there.

You could also supply a file of your choice along with the [`--shell`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption--shell) option to let the command know you want the shell opened on completion of any instructions contained:

```
mongo --shell file_with_javascript.js
```

But as mentioned, the `.mongorc.js` file would still be called (if present) unless the [`--norc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption--norc) option was also specified.